# KSH script missinterpreting alias stored in SQL oracle DB

Tags: ksh, alias, sql

I have stored the path of my file in a table with as an alias (as the complete path was too long for the table's field). However, in my KSH script, when I am doing :

```
nomtmp=`sqlplus -S bla/bla <<ENDOFSQL
 select myPath
   ||'/'
   || 'myFileName'
   || '.xml'   
from myTable;
 exit
ENDOFSQL`
```

(myPath contains $fic)
$fic is not interpreted as an alias, and thus the script is looking for the file in the directory'$fic' it does not interpret it as an alias.

I can't modify the content of my table.
How can I make it knows that it should deal with it as with an alias ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You seem to be asking about the expansion of shell _variables_ within a heredoc - is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your SQL query is returning a substring $ifc that you want expanded to the value of the shell variable when assigning to nomtmp.

If that's the case, you can use a variety of methods to do so, including the shell eval builtin command. Try this:

```
nomtmp=$(eval echo "$(sqlplus -S bla/bla <<ENDOFSQL
 select myPath
   ||'/'
   || 'myFileName'
   || '.xml'   
from myTable;
 exit
ENDOFSQL)")
```

Note that

```
$( ... )
```

is the same as

```
` ... `
```

but the former is preferable since it can be nested. Also note that you may want to use `${ifc}` in your database rather than `$ifc` so that you can use it as a true substring with non-whitespace before and/or after.